# Determinantal rings are Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, matrices

Consider a $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with entries in $R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Let $I$  be the ideal of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors of $M$. Is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n}/I$ Cohen-Macaulay?If not, what additional assumptions we need for an affirmative answer?

Comment: I think in your case for $R/I$ to be CM it is necessary that proj. dim $R/I\leq4$.

Comment: the case that I'm more interested in is when I is of codimension 2.

Comment: @Mahdi: how do you get $4$?


Comment: A sufficient condition is that the quotient ring has the expected dimension. See

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44823/irreducibility-smoothness-of-the-degeneracy-locus/45502#45502

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer is no: consider the ring $k[x_1, x_2] / (x_1^2, x_1 x_2)$ which is not Cohen-Macaulay. However, if you require that the matrix has homogeneous entries and a condition on the height of the ideal $I$, you will have that $k[x_1, \dots, x_n] / I$ is Cohen-Macaulay. You could read the first pages of *Determinantal Ideals* by R. Miro-Roig.

Comment: What is the condition on the height of $I$?

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with codim two CM ideals then you can use Hilbert-Burch theorem. Those CM ideals of ht two are generated by the maximal minors of an n by n-1 matrix where n is the minimal number of generators for the ideals. Eisenbud's comm alg book should have a proof as well as the statement which is in a bit more general setting.

Comment: In Mike Artin's book, some part of the Hilbert-Burch theorem is also attributed to Schaps.